# How Can I download media to specific path on Telethon

Tags: python, file, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm working on telethon download_media and _download_document methods for downloading media from telegram. My code is something like this:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages('me'):
        print(message.id, message.text)

        # You can download media from messages, too!
        # The method will return the path where the file was saved.
        if message.photo:
            path = await message.download_media()
            print('File saved to', path)  # printed after download is done

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

But this code cannot download the media to a specific path,
and How Can I get the name of file that saved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Docs of telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_media) shows that `download_media` method accepts argument named `file`, which is

> The output file path, directory, or stream-like object. If the path
> exists and is a file, it will be overwritten. If file is the type
> bytes, it will be downloaded in-memory as a bytestring (e.g.
> file=bytes).

I do not have ability to test it, but something like replacing

```
message.download_media()
```

with

```
message.download_media(file="path/to/downloads_dir")
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

You Can get File name by Using `message.file.name`, Here is Code

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages('me'):
        print(message.id, message.text)
        if message.photo:
            print('File Name :' + str(message.file.name))
            path = await client.download_media(message.media, "youranypathhere")
            print('File saved to', path)  # printed after download is done

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: but when we using `event` how can we get the file name

Comment: Simpler (and more reliable) solution: `message.file.name`.

Comment: @HelloWord, in my case its message, if in your case its even then use `event.file.name` as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

For Nodejs, gram js the code is:

```js
const buf = await message.downloadMedia({ outputFile: undefined }) as Buffer;

await fs.writeFile('./abc.mp3', buf);
```