# Telethon on Python: How download only photo?

Tags: python, telethon

stackoverflow. I beginer python developter and need help.
I want download foto on my serwer from different telegram chenals. Have htis code, but it download all media including video. **How i can chenge code to download only photo?** I've read the documentation, but don't found the answer. Thank you!

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from tqdm import tqdm

with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_peer="username",
        limit=500,
        hash=0,
    ))

    title = 'Новинки Margaret❤'
    for chat in result.chats:
        print(chat)

        if chat.title == title:
            messages = client.get_messages(chat, limit=1000)

            for message in tqdm(messages):
                message.download_media('./' + title + '/') #I think the problem is right here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning, I try to help you.

I think your problem is how do you read the line:

```
message.download_media('./' + title + '/')
```

Think that in the Telethon documentation it is shown as follows:

```
client.download_media(media, path)
```

I have found a similar bug, try from this already solved question:

[All credits to the user who solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100409/how-can-i-download-media-to-specific-path-on-telethon)

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added a file check. This solved my problem.

```py
  for message in tqdm(messages):
        if type(message.media) == telethon.MessageMediaPhoto: 
            message.download_media('./' + title + '/')
```